# Pyspark code to read from Cassandra table takes almost 14 mints to read 6 GB data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra

Spark cluster I am Using 4 cores and 4 executor instances.
Cassandra table data size after filter is 6GB.
Reading data from this Cassandra table using pyspark code.
Applying filter on partition keys(3 partition key)
Push filter happening.
One of partition key filter is a list of 5000 values.
This simple read is taking more than 14 mint.
Is this expected time or can we acheive this in less time.

Comment: unfortunately the key filter list is translated into `IN` operation that could overload the coordinating node. more effective should be `joinWithCassandra` in the RDD API, or direct join on data frame (but only in DSE version)

Comment: But I am seeing my filter in push filter of physical plan.Is there any chance this push filter not working.

Comment: push filter may work, but it's not necessary that it's most effective thing from Cassandra perspective

Comment: @AlexOtt  I tried joinWithCassandra .It is not available in pyspark. I have read that pysaprk dataframe join do the same as joinwithcassandra in rdd.I used  a broadcast join aftyer load.then I did a count.still this is taking almost 9 mints to laod 70lakhs record.